# Проблема декодирования (.decode('utf-8')): разные результаты в Debian и вызов по Хуку для Windows (скрипт python)

Tags: python, windows, utf-8, telegram, svn

Хочу сделать оповещение в телеграм бот при фиксировании проектов в subversion (SVN). Сервер SVN работает на Debian, svn-клиенты работают на машинах с Windows.
Скрипт для python запускается через Хук (post-commit):

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

python3 "$REPOS"/hooks/bot_tlgrm.py "$REPOS" "$REV"
```

Скрипт запускается с двумя параметрами: путь хранилища (**SVN**) и номер ревизии.
Скрипт может работать и без параметров, отправляя данные о последней ревизии.

При запуске скрипта из консоли на **Debian** декодирование (`.decode('utf-8')`) данных проходит успешно, данные отправляются в чат бота телеграм, имея читаемый вид. Проблема возникает при запуске скрипnа по Хуку **SVN**, при фиксировании любого проекта из **Windows**, символы кириллицы отправляются в виде кодировки.

[Пример проблемы в видео](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MCNzGutm0ltez8nEaboSoMbSZklur3m9)

скрипт на **Python** (`bot_tlgrm.py`):

```
import telegram
import time
import sys
# for SVN
from sys import argv, stderr, exit
from subprocess import check_output

#token that can be generated talking with @BotFather on telegram
my_token = "123456789:AnHj-crWWMLmqpyhsIPTLd7szBAg4vvhHRO"
chat_id_my = 123456789
msg = ''
tmp = ''
msg_tmp = "Активность в репозитории: \n"
msg_tmp = "<b>" + msg_tmp + "</b>"
i = 1
my_len = len(sys.argv)

repo = '/home/svnrepos/'
rev = '3752'
svn_adr_ip = 'svn://192.168.4.1/'

# Ревизия для комментария
if my_len > 2 :
   repo = sys.argv[1]
   rev = sys.argv[2]

while i < my_len :
    msg = msg + sys.argv[i] + "\n"
    i = i + 1

print('REPO:' + repo)
print('REV:' + rev)
# Изменённый проект {
cmd = ('svnlook', 'dirs-changed', repo)
out = check_output(cmd).splitlines()
# tmp = out[0].decode('utf-8')
msg_tmp = msg_tmp + svn_adr_ip + out[0].decode('utf-8') + '\n'  # декодируем ки$

# Дата изменения {
cmd = ('svnlook', 'date', repo)
out = check_output(cmd).splitlines()
msg_tmp = msg_tmp + out[0].decode('utf-8') + '\n'

# Автор изменения {
cmd = ('svnlook', 'author', repo)
out = check_output(cmd).splitlines()
msg_tmp = msg_tmp + out[0].decode('utf-8') + '\n'

# Комментарий изменения {
cmd = ('svnlook', 'log', repo, '--revision', rev)
out = check_output(cmd).splitlines()
for x in out:
     msg_tmp = msg_tmp + x.decode('utf-8') + "\n"

print(msg_tmp)

try:
  bot = telegram.Bot(token=my_token)
  updates = bot.get_updates()
  chat_id = bot.get_updates()[-1].message.chat_id
  # Acvivity write the text
  bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=chat_id, action=telegram.ChatAction.TYPING)
  bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='Дели гусей на 0!')
  bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=msg_tmp, parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML )

except Exception:
  print("Error: bot updates/bot_chat_action/send_message")

print('ok!')
```

Comment: Хм. Чудак-человек, кто тебе сказал, что виндовая консоль будет юникодной хоть когда-нибудь? И не процессить ошибки - так себе метод.

Comment: `.decode("utf-8", "ignore")`

Comment: К сожалению мне ваш ответ не помог.

Comment: Дело в том, что сам скрипт "физически" находиться на Линуксовой (Debian) машине, где  находится серверная часть SVN. Скрипт запускается по хуку (файл post-commit), который находится там же, но инициирует этот хук действие (фиксация проекта)  на клиентских машинах с ОС Windows.  Пример ответа из Телеграмма: "Активность в репозитории: 
svn://192.168.4.1/?\208?\161?\208?\159?\208?\151/C-more/
2018-10-03 13:33:27 +0600 (Wed, 03 Oct 2018)
Dimon
?\208?\148?\208?\190?\208?\177?\208?\176?\208?\178?\208?\187?\208?\181?\208?\189?" здесь кодировка в юникоде (DEC 8 x 2)